# How to Strike out DONE items in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, fonts, faces

I saw some folks have a way to strike out `DONE` items in `org-mode`. How do you do that?

Comment: Please remove the solution from your question and post it as an answer instead. It is perfectly fine to [answer your own question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). There is no need to turn this post into a community wiki, and IMO it shouldn't be closed either (as it is fairly likely that it'll be useful to other people down the line).

Comment: I see. I cut the solution into an answer, but I'll only be able to accept it tomorrow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If of use: I came across [Sacha's post](http://sachachua.com/blog/2012/12/emacs-strike-through-headlines-for-done-tasks-in-org/) that talks about how to do this.

Based on the code in her post and on the feedback from the comments, I now use the code below (I have a light theme). You may note lazy loading, this prevents an 'undefined' error at start up as per a comment in original blog post:

```el
(defun my/modify-org-done-face ()
  (setq org-fontify-done-headline t)
  (set-face-attribute 'org-done nil :strike-through t)
  (set-face-attribute 'org-headline-done nil
                      :strike-through t
                      :foreground "light gray"))

(eval-after-load "org"
  (add-hook 'org-add-hook 'my/modify-org-done-face))
```

Comment: Hi, i seems i can't get it works on my machine. Do you place the add-hook before (require 'org)?

Comment: No, I place it faar down near the bottom. Here is my config file: https://github.com/LeoUfimtsev/ldts/blob/master/.emacs.d/my/orgdotemacs.org#cross-out-done-items

Comment: You might need to restart emacs. Also check that no other package is overriding your fonts there.. As last resourt you could try to start a bare emacs, get it to work and narrow it down from there.

Comment: As a note, I load my org very early in my init.el, before my dotemacs loads. I load it from sources: https://github.com/LeoUfimtsev/ldts/blob/master/.emacs.d/init.el

Comment: Hi, i tried to only load the org package and this snippet, but i still not working. btw, nice init file.

Comment: @yi.tang.uni which version of emacs are you using? (I'm using latest version 25.4, maybe your version is out of date?) If using some fork like aquamacs, try the main emacs to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Hi, i am using GNU Emacs 24.4.1 on Ubuntu and org-mode 8.2.10, I will try to update and see.

Comment: What does `add-hook 'org-add-hook` mean?

Comment: This correctly changes the color of DONE headlines, but it doesn't strike them through for me ...